# ConTeXt: How to prevent new paragraph after \hrule in section heading?

Tags: sectioning, context, rules

I'm using ConTeXt, and trying to setup my document's subsection headings to start with a colored rule. However, any way I've tried doing this results in a rule placed a line higher than the heading text.

The simplest document that illustrates the issue is the following:

```
\startmode[*mkii]
  \enableregime[utf-8]
  \setupcolors[state=start]
\stopmode

\setuphead[section]      [style=\tfb, before={beforetext}]
\setuphead[subsection]   [style=\tfb, before={\blackrule}]

\starttext

\section{Section}
This works as expected.

\subsection{Subsection}
Here, for some reason the rule doesn't come on the same line as the heading.
However, inlining does seem to work in the section text: \blackrule
\stoptext
```

which gets rendered as

[image: rule rendering test]

Does anyone know what causes the line break when the rule is part of the section heading, and how to prevent it?

Comment: Rules don’t cause TeX to enter horizontal mode as text does. Try ``\setuphead[subsection][style=\tfb, before=\leavevmode\blackrule]`` (or ``\dontleavehmode\blackrule``). See also http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Unexpected_behavior#Unsolicited_Vertical_Mode

Comment: @phg would you be so kind and write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to `\leavevmode` explicitly before of the rule:

```
\startmode[*mkii]
  \enableregime[utf-8]
  \setupcolors[state=start]
\stopmode

\setuphead[section]   [style=\tfb, before={beforetext}]
\setuphead[subsection][style=\tfb, before=\leavevmode\blackrule]

\starttext

\section{Section}
This works as expected.

\subsection{Subsection}
Here, for some reason the rule doesn't come on the same line as the heading.
However, inlining does seem to work in the section text: \blackrule
\stoptext
```